# confused about this sentence

Tags: grammar, reading

it is simple enough to say that since books have classes, we should separate them and ***take from each what it is right that each should give us***

I bold the sentence that makes me confused, I can't figure it out that what does it mean, but I guess it means:

1. we separate books
2. we get what certain classified book should give us

am i making myself understood? need help, I don't really get this sentence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context I cannot say what is meant by “classes”, but the bold part is not too hard: each book has something to give us; the nature of that something depends on its class; we should not try to find in a book that which is not in it.

Comment: thank you : )    i get it. have a nice day